# Ошибка при открытии страницы определенного поста First argument to get_object_or_404() must be a Model, Manager, or QuerySet, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

Файл views.py:

```py
    from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
    from django.views.generic import View

    from .models import Post, Tag
    from .utils import ObjectDetailMixin

    class PostDetail(ObjectDetailMixin, View):
        models = Post
        template = 'blog/post_detail.html'


    class TagDetail(ObjectDetailMixin, View):
        models = Tag
        template = 'blog/tag_detail.html'


    def posts_list(request):
        posts = Post.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'blog/index.html', context={'posts': posts})


    def tags_list(request):
        tags = Tag.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'blog/tags_list.html', context={'tags': tags})
```

Файл utils.py:

```py
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


    class ObjectDetailMixin:
        model = None
        template = None

        def get(self, request, slug):
            obj = get_object_or_404(self.model, slug__iexact=slug)
            return render(request, self.template, context={self.model.__name__.lower(): obj})
```

Файл urls.py (на всякий случай):

```py
    from django.urls import path
    from .views import *


    urlpatterns = [
        path('', posts_list, name='posts_list_url'),
        path('post/<str:slug>/', PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail_url'),
        path('tags/', tags_list, name='tags_list_url'),
        path('tag/<str:slug>', TagDetail.as_view(), name='tag_detail_url'),
    ]
```

Полный текст ошибки:

```
Internal Server Error: /post/post-1/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mark/Рабочий стол/django-blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/mark/Рабочий стол/django-blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/mark/Рабочий стол/django-blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/mark/Рабочий стол/django-blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mark/Рабочий стол/django-blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mark/Рабочий стол/django-blog/app/blogengine/blog/views.py", line 12, in get
    obj = get_object_or_404(self.model, slug__iexact=slug)
  File "/home/mark/Рабочий стол/django-blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 90, in get_object_or_404
    "or QuerySet, not '%s'." % klass__name
ValueError: First argument to get_object_or_404() must be a Model, Manager, or QuerySet, not 'NoneType'.
```

Comment: Представьте, пожалуйста, полный текст ошибки. Особенно строку и файл, в которых она зафиксирована

Comment: Добавил, ошибка в файле utils.py, там, где вызывается метод get_object_or_404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не вникать в подробности, проблема в том, что в классе объявлено `model = None` и далее `model` никак не переопределяется. Таким образом, при обращении к `self.model`, метод получает `None`, имеющий тип `NoneType`, как указано в ошибке.

Следовательно, необходимо инициализировать свойство `model` в классе каким-либо соответствующим значением.

Comment: Вот в этом видео на 14.50 https://youtu.be/hM6cevQ7Mig?t=884 он проверяет работоспособность кода и у него всё работает, хотя model и template = None

Comment: @MarkMel К сожалению, я сейчас не имею возможности посмотреть видео, однако предполагаю, что в примере, представленном там, значения заполняются неявно, что у Вас не происходит. Пока что могу посоветовать только разобраться в том, как и где происходит заполнение этих значений.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @MarkMel Всегда рад помочь.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Изменил в файле urls.py строки:

```py
    path('post/<str:slug>/', PostDetail.as_view(),
    path('tag/<str:slug>', TagDetail.as_view(),
```

на:

```py
    path('post/<str:slug>/', PostDetail.as_view(model=Post),
    path('tag/<str:slug>', TagDetail.as_view(model=Tag),
```

И я до сих пор не могу понять, как это помогло.

Comment: Если вы что-то не , поняли, спросите увтора принятого ответа или задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: Очевидно, аргумент `model` из метода `PostDetail.as_view(model=Post)` каким-то образом передаётся в объект класса `ObjectDetailMixin`, инициализируя в нём свойство `model`.